# How to run code on jre9 that was compiled with jdk8 and use Unsafe

Tags: java-9, backwards-compatibility, unsafe

I have code that was compiled with jdk8 as target and source for java 1.8 and use Unsafe. I tried to run this program with jdk9 but it fails with following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.misc.Unsafe.getByte
```

Package sun.misc.Unsafe is not removed from jdk9, so I expected the code to run. I can not recompile the code with jdk9, I expected that java should be backward compatible.

I create little test that is not working for me.
Test class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import sun.misc.Unsafe;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    System.out.println("before");
    Field theUnsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
    theUnsafeField.setAccessible(true);

    Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) theUnsafeField.get(null);
    unsafe.getByte(new Object(), 4);
    System.out.println("after");
  }
}
```

Then I compile the code with jdk8.

```
C:\Java-IDE\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac.exe Test.java
```

Then if I run it with jdk8 it works:

```
C:\Java-IDE\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe Test
before
after
```

If i run it with jdk9 it throws exception:

```
C:\Java-IDE\jdk-9.0.4_windows-x64_bin\bin\java.exe Test
before
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.misc.Unsafe.getByte(Ljava/lang/Object;I)B
        at Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

I believe it should be also possible to run it under jdk9. Is it possible?

Comment: You probably just need to add the `jdk.unsupported` module - try `--add-modules=jdk.unsupported` on the command line or update the project's module info if it has one.

Comment: Yes, I am running with --add-modules=jdk.unsupported but it still throwing the exception

Comment: Something fishy here. The method still exists in JDK 9 and JDK 10. Please tell us more on how you are running this?

Comment: I am using Intellij, I have the project that is compiled with jdk8 with target and source set as 1.8 java. Then I try to run the compiled code with the jdk9.

Comment: Its working fine if I compiled it with jdk9 but if i compiled it with jdk8 its not working

Comment: @AlanBateman I added simple test code that is not working for me.

Comment: I see the issue, getByte(Object,int) was removed. Cast the 4 to (long)4 so that you are use the getByte(Object,long) method.

Comment: @AlanBateman Thank you very much I see it know. I noticed it before, but I was confused because the code was compilable under jdk9 so I didnt think this is the reason. I have the same code in the legacy application that I can not recompiled with jdk9. So if I understand it correctly, there is no way how to run this code with java9.

Comment: Right, you need to recompile the code (with JDK 8) to use getByte(Object,long). Then it will run on both JDK 8 and JDK 9.

Comment: @HPCS please take a look at my edited answer

Answer (score 3):

The method `byte Unsafe.getByte(Object, int)` has been removed in Java 9, but recompiling fixes the issue, as it will cause the invocation of `byte Unsafe.getByte(Object, long)` then, which is indeed the intended replacement.

Note that even besides the fact that `Unsafe` is an unofficial, unsupported API that should not be used by applications, the methods using `int` offsets are deprecated in favor of methods using `long` since `1.4.1`, which means that there were one and a half decades time to adapt old code, but your statement that the code “was compiled with jdk8 as target” indicates that it is actually even younger than that.

Given the fact that the planned entire removal of `sun.misc.Unsafe` has been announced multiple times, there will be no way around changing the code, if it shall run on future JVM versions. If you are not able to recompile it, ask yourself, how the future maintenance of code that you can’t recompile should look like. If the code is supposed to be frozen, freeze the JVM version as well. Otherwise, you need to find a way to recompile it or replace it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes java is backward compatible, but it is for the java API.
The package sun.misc is one of the packages that Sun/Oracle advertised as moveable/updatable/deletable without any prior warning.

So it was

To answer your question, you will need to update your code

EDIT:

Like Alan Bateman said in his comment the obvious solution would be to recompile

But if you can't and if you're not against ugly hacks you can :

1. get the source of sun.misc.Unsafe and insert your needed/missing methods
2. create a custom classloader which will essentialy do the same as the system classloader but when sun.misc.Unsafe will be requested for loading will load your version of Unsafe instead
3. Start your application with your custom classloader

   java -Djava.system.class.loader=com.xxx.MyCustomClassLoader xxx

Ugly but may work without recompiling

Comment: It was not removed http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260. I can not recompile the code. Unsafe should be possible to use under jdk9 as well.

Comment: It hasn't been removed - it is still there but is in the `jdk.unsupported` module

Comment: It seems "Unsafe" was "updated" by removing the getByte method

Comment: No the method getByte was not removed.

Comment: @gre-449 I run it with the --add-modules jdk.unsupported .

Comment: To aleviate your pain i would say "you're not alone", check this https://blog.dripstat.com/removal-of-sun-misc-unsafe-a-disaster-in-the-making/ . If the class is still here in jdk9 it may disapear completely in jdk10

Comment: Its the article from 2015(when people thought that it will be remove), at the end the Unsafe was not removed, because it was used by many projects.

Comment: Sure "Unsafe" is safe for now, but the future of this class seems compromised

Comment: Well, be it now or future the above stands no more than a comment IMHO. Downvoting for low quality.

Comment: @Mumrah81 *sun.misc.Unsafe* is alive and well in Java 10 :)

Comment: @Sartorius "Most internal APIs will be inaccessible by default, but some critical, widely-used internal ones will remain accessible ***until supported replacements exist***" quoted from https://blogs.oracle.com/java/prepare-for-java-se-9

Comment: @nullpointer Ok for the downvote the answer is realy a low quality one but please take into account the original question before it was edited.

Comment: @Mumrah81 indeed, if the answer is updated to match up the quality I can revert my vote as well. Do let me know, once you update with a proper solution.

Comment: @nullpointer still a low quality answer but at least it is a proper solution

Comment: @Mumrah81 Well, *VarHandle* (the supported replacement) does exist since 9.